# XCode debugger does not show all the variables content. Is it a bug?

Tags: ios, xcode, variables, debugging

I don't understand why I can view some variables content but not some others in XCode-11.6.

I attach a screenshot to show you an example of what I see. On the left part I can't see the content of variable `_rowsStack`, but from the console, on the right, with `po` I can see correctly the variable content.

Any ideas ?

[image: xcode debugger screenshot]